# How to use Python script as a cordova plugin in angular project?

Tags: python, angular, cordova-plugins

I am trying to build some mobile chatbot app that might be based on angular. but it's back ends will be python. My python file will call different models and give some results. The problem is: I don't want to call the API endpoint-based solution. Mostly these are done through flask where python is deployed to form API. Instead, I want the python files will be deployed offline along with the front end.

There is a project

> https://pypi.org/project/python-for-android/

After skimming through the document, I am somehow lost (looking at the installment guides) and need some help.

Firstly in my perspective, I need to deploy only a very basic python file. Here the input is a string and it will return an output

**test.py**

```
def my_function( input): 
  return "processed " + input
```

Keeping in mind I have just this python file to deploy

My question :

1. Which steps are needed to make my simple python code to a state where I can be used for the next steps?

2.what steps to make from that previous state of python to a cordova plugin?

Finally combined together with a very basic angular/cordova project (where I have just text box + a button and a span. <> then I click the button it calls my function and gets the output).

It would be quite helpful if you could demonstrate these questions as a start stone project.

**NB**
I was looking in cordova custom plugin development guides. But don't know how to write a plugin using Python.

https://medium.com/ionic-and-the-mobile-web/how-to-write-cordova-plugins-864e40025f2